# How do you check a condition from a reply to a query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, coldfusion

I need to bcc someone if `agencyType_ID` in the `company` table is 2. How do I do this? So far I've got

```
<cfquery name="checkAgencyType" datasource="#APPLICATION.primaryDSN#">
    SELECT * FROM company WHERE agencyType_ID=2
</cfquery>
```

And inside the `<cfmail>` I would have

```
<cfif query=”checkAgencyType”>bcc=”joe@example.com”></cfmail>
```

EDIT: I should've mentioned I already have it working to send mails using to and cc fields so I'd rather not refactor a bunch of code. But most of the replies seem not to need this :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use the attribute collection argument. It allows you to pass attributes to a tag as a structure. This way you can define your static attributes and then dynamically add any others. As long as the attribute key names match they will get passed to the tag.

```
<cfset args = {
    from = "from@gmail.com",
    to = "to@gmail.com",
    subject = "My Subject",
    type = "HTML"
}>

<cfif checkAgencyType.agencyType_ID EQ 2>
    <cfset args.bcc = "joe@example.com">
</cfif>

<cfmail attributeCollection="#args#">
    content...
</cfmail>
```

Comment: This is one of the things I love about ColdFusion... here we have different answers and multiple ways to solve the problem, all valid, with different styles depending on specific needs and development style.  I love this language. :)

Answer (score 2):

you're on the right track, you'd just want to set it as a variable.

```
<cfset bccaddress = '' />
<cfif checkAgencyType.RecordCount>
  <cfset bccaddress = 'joe@example.com' />
</cfif>
```

This assumes that by having a record returned in your query you want to add a bcc address.

Then include it in your tag by using `<cfmail to="test@address.com" from="test2@address.com" subject="My subject" bcc="#bccaddress#">`

Comment: Would it work if I set the variable to bcc="joe@example.com" so if the RecordCount is 0 there would be no bcc at all (instead of bcc="")? See what I'm saying or no?

Comment: @Celeritas no, that will not work.  it won't hurt to have bcc="" in the cfquery tag.  You cannot store tag attributes in a variable.  You can store a value that is passed to that attribute, but not the attribute as "attr='some value'", that is not valid CF syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an "inline if" to check the query for a result and, if found, set an e-mail address.  Otherwise, it will set the bcc attribute to be blank.

```
<cfmail
  subject="Subject"
  from="you@example.com"
  to="customer@example.com"
  bcc="#iif(checkAgencyType.recordCount, de('joe@example.com'), de(''))#"
>
  This is a cool message.
</cfmail>
```